# Inserting records manually into an exisiting sqlite file present in project through sqlite browser is not showing up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I already have a sqlite file within the project with pre-populated values in it. The app is in the app store.Now, I need to do a new release and for that  I need to pre populate some new values into sqlite file. I tried manually opening the sqlite file present in the project and added new records using sqlite browser. when i install the new app(ipa) over the existing app(ipa), the new records I added is not showing up. When i uninstall the old app(ipa) and install the new app(ipa) the records are showing up. can anyone let me know me how solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think, as you are copying your database inside your project first time if `.sqlite` file not contain at particular location.

So you have to remove old database from location where you have put your `.sqlite` file and then copy new one when application launch.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello,
It is not possible Sq Lite database not show your record. If you insert a properly then definitely it will display to you. Please follow This step might be help you.**

1)Open your project then show Database in finder.

2)Open Database in browser.

3)Insert value You want.

4)Close browser and open database again ,Show record is already there.

if you don't have new record in database then your record not insert properly and **Keep in mind remove old application first.**